Want to use toaster service inside an interceptor in angular 17 with Standalone false
This is my interceptor and I have a toaster service. When I don't use the service it works good however when I use the toaster it is not working. My page becomes blank. I have imported the service in the app.config file in providers array. Can you please help me fix this thing or what is the correct way to do it.
I tried implementing both class based and functional based interceptor. HOwever it is not working. I was able to trigger the debugger on the toaster using the class based interceptor however it does not pop up. The toaster service is working fine with other components.
import { HttpInterceptorFn, HttpResponse } from '@angular/common/http';
import { inject } from '@angular/core';
import { MToasterService } from '../../../shared/services/toaster/toaster.service';
import { tap } from 'rxjs';

export const merrorInterceptor: HttpInterceptorFn = (req, next) => {
  const toaster = inject(MToasterService)
  return next(req).pipe(
    tap((event: any)=>{
      if(event instanceof HttpResponse && event.status == 401){
        console.log("Error Occurred")
        toaster.showError("Something happened", "Error")
      }
    })
  );
};  


This the toaster service


import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
import { MessageService } from 'primeng/api';
import { CONSTANTS } from '../../../core/utils/app-constants';

@Injectable({
  providedIn: 'root',
})
export class MToasterService {
  config = {
    life: 3000,
    position: 'bottom-right',
  };

  constructor(private messageService: MessageService) {}

  showSuccess(message: string, title?: string) {
    this.messageService.clear();
    this.messageService.add({
      key: CONSTANTS.toasterSeverity.toasterKey,
      severity: CONSTANTS.toasterSeverity.success,
      summary: title || CONSTANTS.toasterMsg.success,
      detail: message,
      life: this.config.life,
    });
  }

  showInfo(message: string, title?: string) {
    this.messageService.clear();
    this.messageService.add({
      key: CONSTANTS.toasterSeverity.toasterKey,
      severity: CONSTANTS.toasterSeverity.info,
      summary: title || CONSTANTS.toasterMsg.info,
      detail: message,
      life: this.config.life,
    });
  }

  showWarn(message: string, title?: string) {
    this.messageService.clear();
    this.messageService.add({
      key: CONSTANTS.toasterSeverity.toasterKey,
      severity: CONSTANTS.toasterSeverity.warn,
      summary: title || CONSTANTS.toasterMsg.warn,
      detail: message,
      life: this.config.life,
    });
  }

  showError(message: string, title?: string) {
    this.messageService.clear();
    this.messageService.add({
      key: CONSTANTS.toasterSeverity.toasterKey,
      severity: CONSTANTS.toasterSeverity.error,
      summary: title || CONSTANTS.toasterMsg.error,
      detail: message,
      life: this.config.life,
    });
  }
}




do you have any console errors? please provide a simple stackblitz where the issue happens

The interceptor is working fine. However when I inject the toaster service it does not work. And there is no error in the console

Also the the api does not get triggered

The reason the popup did not open are as follows, make sure you followed the below steps!

Ensure you provided the MessageService and provideHttpClient(withInterceptors([merrorInterceptor])), in the providers array of bootstrapApplication

Ensure <p-messages></p-messages> is present in the root component, this will be used to show the messages on the UI

The imports MessageModule, MessagesModule, ButtonModule must be imported in the root standalone module.

Finally, the main reason I was not getting the popup was because I had to exclude the property key from the object that is sent to the popup service


example:
this.messageService.add({
  // key: CONSTANTS.toasterSeverity.toasterKey,
  severity: CONSTANTS.toasterSeverity.error,
  summary: title || CONSTANTS.toasterMsg.error,
  detail: message,
  life: this.config.life,
});

Full code:
service:
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
import { MessageService } from 'primeng/api';

export const CONSTANTS = {
  toasterSeverity: {
    toasterKey: 'test',
    success: 'success',
    info: 'info',
    warn: 'warn',
    error: 'error',
  },
  toasterMsg: {
    success: 'working!',
    info: 'working!',
    warn: 'working!',
    error: 'working!',
  },
};

@Injectable({
  providedIn: 'root',
})
export class MToasterService {
  config = {
    life: 3000,
    position: 'bottom-right',
  };

  constructor(private messageService: MessageService) {}

  showSuccess(message: string, title?: string) {
    this.messageService.add({
      // key: CONSTANTS.toasterSeverity.toasterKey,
      severity: CONSTANTS.toasterSeverity.success,
      summary: title || CONSTANTS.toasterMsg.success,
      detail: message,
      life: this.config.life,
    });
  }

  showInfo(message: string, title?: string) {
    this.messageService.clear();
    this.messageService.add({
      // key: CONSTANTS.toasterSeverity.toasterKey,
      severity: CONSTANTS.toasterSeverity.info,
      summary: title || CONSTANTS.toasterMsg.info,
      detail: message,
      life: this.config.life,
    });
  }

  showWarn(message: string, title?: string) {
    this.messageService.clear();
    this.messageService.add({
      // key: CONSTANTS.toasterSeverity.toasterKey,
      severity: CONSTANTS.toasterSeverity.warn,
      summary: title || CONSTANTS.toasterMsg.warn,
      detail: message,
      life: this.config.life,
    });
  }

  showError(message: string, title?: string) {
    this.messageService.clear();
    this.messageService.add({
      // key: CONSTANTS.toasterSeverity.toasterKey,
      severity: CONSTANTS.toasterSeverity.error,
      summary: title || CONSTANTS.toasterMsg.error,
      detail: message,
      life: this.config.life,
    });
  }
}

main.ts
import { Component, importProvidersFrom } from '@angular/core';
import {
  HttpClient,
  HttpClientModule,
  provideHttpClient,
  withInterceptors,
} from '@angular/common/http';
import { bootstrapApplication } from '@angular/platform-browser';
import 'zone.js';
import { merrorInterceptor } from './app/dummy.interceptor';
import { MessageService } from 'primeng/api';
import { provideAnimations } from '@angular/platform-browser/animations';
import { ButtonModule } from 'primeng/button';
import { MessageModule } from 'primeng/message';
import { MessagesModule } from 'primeng/messages';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-root',
  standalone: true,
  imports: [MessageModule, MessagesModule, ButtonModule],
  providers: [],
  template: `
    <div>
      <button type="button" pButton class="p-button-primary" (click)="callApiHandler()" label="Test"></button>
    </div>
    <p-messages></p-messages>
  `,
})
export class App {
  constructor(
    private http: HttpClient,
    private messageService: MessageService
  ) {}

  callApiHandler() {
    this.http.get('/test').subscribe((res) => {});
  }
}

bootstrapApplication(App, {
  providers: [
    MessageService,
    provideAnimations(),
    importProvidersFrom(HttpClientModule),
    provideHttpClient(withInterceptors([merrorInterceptor])),
  ],
});

interceptor
import {
  HttpErrorResponse,
  HttpInterceptorFn,
  HttpResponse,
} from '@angular/common/http';
import { inject } from '@angular/core';
import { catchError, of, tap, throwError } from 'rxjs';
import { MToasterService } from './toaster.service';

export const merrorInterceptor: HttpInterceptorFn = (req, next) => {
  const toaster = inject(MToasterService);
  return next(req).pipe(
    catchError((err: any) => {
      if (err instanceof HttpErrorResponse) {
        // Handle HTTP errors
        if (err.status === 200) {
          console.log('Error Occurred');
          toaster.showError('Something happened', 'Error');
        }
      } else {
        console.log('Error Occurred');
        toaster.showError('Something happened', 'Error');
      }

      // Re-throw the error to propagate it further
      return throwError(() => err);
    })
  );
};

Stackblitz Demo
